# knockoutjs - custom binding nested inside template, attr not bound yet on custom binding call

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a custom binding inside a template.

The custom binding involves attributes rendered with attrs bound to the template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="mc-radio-template">
        <!-- ko foreach: Values -->
        <div class="rounded_col" data-bind="complexRadio: $parent.Value">
            <label data-bind="text: Description"></label>
            <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" data-bind="attr: { 'name': $parent.Name, 'value': Value}" />
        </div>            
        <!-- /ko -->
    </script>
```

complexRadio involves the input's value which is rendered by the template using the attr binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.complexRadio = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Get radio button located inside this div
        var radio = $(element).find('input[type="radio"]');
        var isDisabled = !!radio.attr('disabled');

        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

        if (valueUnwrapped === true)
            valueUnwrapped = 'true';

        if (valueUnwrapped === false)
            valueUnwrapped = 'false';

        value(valueUnwrapped);

        // When div is clicked, check the radio and trigger radio change event
        if (!isDisabled)
            $(element).click(function () {
                radio.prop('checked', true);
                radio.change();
            });

        // When radio button is checked, update the viewModel property!!
        $(radio).change(function () {
            if (radio.prop('checked'))  // only if it was changed to checked
            {
                // Set viewModel property to value of the radio button that was clicked
                var value = valueAccessor();

                value(radio.val());
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

        if (valueUnwrapped === true)
            valueUnwrapped = 'true';

        if (valueUnwrapped === false)
            valueUnwrapped = 'false';


        // Get radio button located inside this div
        var radio = $(element).find('input[type="radio"]');

        // Set radio to be checked or unchecked
        var shouldBeChecked = valueUnwrapped == radio.val();
        if (shouldBeChecked)
            radio.parent().addClass('active');
        else
            radio.parent().removeClass('active');
    }
};
```

my issue is that the complexRadio init happens before the value attribute is rendered by the template.

on this line -

```
var shouldBeChecked = valueUnwrapped == radio.val();
```

radio.val() is not the one that's rendered after the template is done rendering.
This causes the beginning state of the radio to be unchecked.

How can I force the custom binding to run after the rendering is over?
Or maybe - how to add the custom binding using js so i can add it in the afterRender callback.

Comment: What does !! do in var isDisabled =  !!radio.attr('disabled');?

Comment: @Bindrid it's a way to cast a value to a boolean.

Comment: are you binding change to an empty handler on purpose or do you mean to    do radio.trigger('change')  or radio.off('change') instead of radio.change()?

Comment: radio.change fires on on/off events (changes to the checked value of the radio). all of this code works just fine, the issue is with 'var shouldBeChecked = valueUnwrapped == radio.val();' because the value is not rendered yet by the template on the first update call

Comment: because then it would be one-way, i need it to reflect the viewmodel even if the value changes on the viewmodel side - that's why it has to be on the update. in the handler i trigger the update too.

Comment: plus - i can force an update when the radio is rendered with it's real value after the first update, but that would be a very specific use-case of that binding in relation to using it within a template, i would like to keep it cleaner as i use it outside of templates usualy

Comment: It just needs to bind it after it is finished rendering the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `value` binding on the radio, and you're using jQuery to access its `value` attribute, but the radio isn't bound until after the outer binding is applied. It's not true that the radio isn't rendered, it just isn't bound.

The solution is to have the outer binding control the binding of the contained radio. See [the documentation on descendant bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html).

Comment: I guess rendered is not the right term, bound is right, it is not bound yet.

Comment: I didn't quite get the use of the descendant bindings, can you give me an example? i need to use ko.applyBindingsToDescendants in the init and that should solve it? worked :)

Comment: Yes, use `applyBindingsToDescendants` and `return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };` from the `init`, as in the second example on the documentation page.